# replacing mysql_result with mysqli code

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to find a suitable code to replace `mysql_result` in the following code:

```
$per_page = 9;

 $page_query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM products");
 $pages = ceil(mysql_result($page_query, 0) / $per_page);

 $page = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;
 $start = ($page - 1) * $per_page;

 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products  ORDER BY product_id DESC LIMIT $start, $per_page");
```

this is what I have done, but i am not sure it will work:

```
$per_page = 9;
  $page_query = $conn->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM food");
  $pages = ceil(fetch_assoc($page_query, 0) / $per_page);

  $page = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;
  $start = ($page - 1) * $per_page;

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM food  ORDER BY food_id DESC LIMIT $start, $per_page";
```

will `$pages = ceil(fetch_assoc($page_query, 0) / $per_page);`  work?

Comment: This appears to be a basic question about pagination, so why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: i am using mysqli not mysql, i got that code but it is written in basic mysql format which i am not using in my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mysqli is not recommended to be used as is.

This is why PDO is recommended as a mysql ext replacement

```
$per_page = 9; 
$count = $conn->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM food")->fetchColumn();
$pages = ceil($count / $per_page);
```

see, it's even simpler than your old code.

Here is a [PDO tutorial](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo) I wrote, that you can try and see how dramatically it can simplify your tasks.

Comment: it brings an error: call to undefined method mysqli_result::fetchColumn()

Comment: Did you ever read the answer? Or just grabbed the code and hastily pasted it in your script?

Comment: I'm recommending mysqli. There. It's recommended. More importantly, I'm also recommending prepared statements.

Comment: @Strawberry after reading this article [Usability problems of mysqli compared to PDO](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/mysqli_comparison), you will change your mind.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use mysqli and after excecute the query you have to fetch as array or object then based on count you proceed. In below i mentioned some changes. Try it, it may help you

```
<?php

$per_page = 9;

$page_query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM products");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($page_query);
$page = ceil($row['count'], 0) / $per_page);

 $start = ($page - 1) * $per_page;

 $result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM products  ORDER BY product_id DESC LIMIT $start, $per_page");
```

Comment: brings this error: `Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_result() in .. `

Comment: i modified try once again